# c++ with vcl: closing secondary form does not end process

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm still learning c++ with vcl forms so forgive me if what I'm asking turns out to be simpler than it seems.  For reference, I'm using c++ builder 10.1 berlin in a Windows environment.

I have a program with two forms (lets call them "MainForm" and "BackupForm").  I am accepting user input in MainForm, then when the user clicks a particular button ("DoSomething") that action sets a few variables then calls `BackupForm->Show();` then `MainForm->Hide();` to switch over to the second form which does more things.

The issue I'm having is this:  if a user clicks the "X" in the upper right that normally closes a program, it only closes the BackupForm and does not end the process.  If I did the same action on the MainForm it ends the process.

I looked around and either wasn't asking the right question or no-one but me has this issue, or perhaps hiding/showing to switch forms isn't the right way to go about it, but my overall question is this:

**TLDR:** *Is there a way/method/etc. to detect the "close window" button being pressed on a secondary form and subsequently close the application, ending it's process without having to kill it in task manager?*

If there's a better way to be switching forms that I'm unaware of, I wouldn't mind suggestions towards that end as well.

Also, if needed, I can post more of the code but I wasn't sure what would actually be helpful.  Below is some of what I have:

Main (Function? Application?) Pre-generated by my IDE:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
USEFORM("BackupFormCode.cpp", BackupForm);
USEFORM("UserBackupProgram.cpp", MainForm);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TMainForm), &MainForm);
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TBackupForm), &BackupForm);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Button "DoSomething" Pressed in "MainForm":

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::ExecuteCopyClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    //Setting variables.... 
    //Then:
    BackupForm->Show();
    MainForm->Hide(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainForm` is being auto-created first, so it gets set as the `Application->MainForm`.

When the `Application->MainForm` is actually closed, it calls `Application->Terminate()`, causing `Application->Run()` to exit, thus allowing `WinMain()` to exit and the process to terminate.

When you show `BackupForm`, you are merely *hiding* the `MainForm`, not *closing* it.  So `Application->Terminate()` is not getting called.

If you want the process to terminate when `BackupForm` is closed, you need to either:

- `Close()` the `Application->MainForm`:

  ```
  void __fastcall TBackupForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
  {
      Application->MainForm->Close(); 
  }
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  void __fastcall TMainForm::ExecuteCopyClick(TObject *Sender)
  {
      //Setting variables.... 
      //Then:
      Hide(); 
      BackupForm->ShowModal();
      Close();
  }
  ```
- just call `Application->Terminate()` directly:

  ```
  void __fastcall TBackupForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
  {
      Application->Terminate(); 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  For some reason, adding the two `FormClose` methods didn't work in my code, but the second solution with `ShowModal` seemed to work just fine.

Comment: It is not enough to just add the `FormClose()` methods to the code, you need to actually assign them to the `OnClose` events.  They work just fine when used correctly.

Comment: How do you assign the FormClose method to the OnClose event?  I'm struggling to find documentation of how to do so...

Comment: You can assign it using the Object Inspector at design-time, or assign it in code at run-time like any other property.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior. Both forms are auto-created, so closing the second form will not terminate the application...main form is still alive.
You can solve this in several ways. Here is the quick one:

Show second form as modal:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::ExecuteCopyClick(TObject *Sender)
      {
      this->Hide();
      BackupForm->ShowModal();
      this->Show();
      }
```

Now, the BackupForm has "full control" because it's shown as modal form. After BackupForm is closed, you can either show again your main form (as in example above), or close the main form.